# Are there popular English sayings to express “Big fuss, tiny result”?

Tags: expressions

The recent EL&U question asked by Mikhail about the alternative expressions of ‘To shoot out of cannon into sparrows’ reminded me of Japanese saying - 大山鳴動鼠一匹- literally meaning people find (get) “Only a small mouse coming out after hearing rumblings and experiencing shaking of the big mountain, (and jumping out of the house)” which I believe was imported from Chinese classic literature.

I think it has a different meaning from “Shoot sparrows with cannon” and “Chop a chicken using the blade for cow.” Instead it means “a very small result attained with great effort” or “marginal consequence or gain after making a big fuss”

Are there similar English sayings to express “大山鳴動鼠一匹 - Big fuss, tiny result”?

Comment: Related [Word or phrase for 'a much hyped discovery which later turns out to be insignificant or of no value'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100452/word-or-phrase-for-a-much-hyped-discovery-which-later-turns-out-to-be-insignifi), [“To shoot out of cannon into sparrows”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100218/to-shoot-out-of-cannon-into-sparrows)

Comment: Funny, the Japanese saying exists, 1:1, in German as well: “Der Berg kreißte und gebar eine Maus”. It’s apparently derived from Latin (Horace: “Parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus” – “the mountains are in labour, they will bear a ridiculous mouse”).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know a similar one in Spanish: "mucho ruido y pocas nueces", (lots of noise and a few nuts)

Comment: @KonradRudolph  The proverbial English translation is "The mountains laboured and brought forth a mouse".

Comment: @StoneyB If that’s idiomatic, it should be an answer, no?

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's most definitely not a popular english saying.

Comment: @Yoichi: I must admit I'm surprised to see we *still* don't seem to have an everyday expression with exactly the meaning I assume you're looking for. Most of our idioms so far imply disproportionate reaction to *something [slightly] bad that has arisen*, rather than disproportionate effort required to achieve some insignificant benefit. But I think dpatchery's *"I [made a lot of effort] and **all I got was this lousy** [t-shirt]"* comes pretty close.

Comment: I've heard cricket commentators say "big boast, small roast"

Comment: Apparently it's an [urban myth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Pen) that NASA spent millions/billions developing a pen that would write in zero-gravity. Anyway - the Russian astronauts solved their problem by using pencils!

Comment: This seems loosely analogous to "Crying over spilt milk," but perhaps not similar enough to list an an official Answer.

Comment: There are contexts in which "more trouble than it is/was worth" would capture this succinctly.

Answer (score 38):

I think Shakespeare's [*Much Ado About Nothing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Much_Ado_About_Nothing) is quite relevant. In more contemporary English "a lot of fuss [over/about] nothing" means the same thing.

Comment: Same drawback as *storm in a teacup* - these are expressions normally used where the "fuss" is a reaction to some trivial but unwanted situation, rather than a [disproportionately small] *goal/end result* of much effort.

Comment: It's a poetic saying, however, I can't help but remember that the title is a double entendre on a bit of old slang.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I added another answer that might be more satisfactory.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 21):

I have heard people speak of "making a molehill out of a mountain" (an inversion of the more common ["making a mountain out of a molehill"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mountain_out_of_a_molehill)).

Comment: It's the original, "making a mountain out of a molehill" that's wanted here.

Comment: @Max I'm trying to sort out whether I agree with you or not. Depending on how you twist it, either version of the aphorism could work. At any rate, I think Jim's Much Ado About Nothing is the answer here.

Comment: "Making a molehill out of a mountain" is making very little fuss (a molehill) about something big (a mountain)

Comment: General comment about the flexibility/ambiguity of English: my answer and @Max's comment have at the time of writing the same number of up votes. Fascinating!

Answer (score 19):

I'm not certain it meets OP's exact definition, but a [storm in a teacup](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/storm+in+a+teacup.html)* might fit. It's usually used where the fuss is over some *undesirable* thing, rather than a trivial but (slightly) desired outcome.

Another possibility is [don't sweat the small stuff](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/don%27t+sweat+the+small+stuff.html) *(used to tell people not to worry about trivial or unimportant issues)*. It can be used as *don't expend too much **effort** [to achieve some trivial gain]*, but it's normally advising what *not* to do, rather than a description of what you *did* for little gain.

There's always [this graffiti](http://dictionary.babylon.com/penny/), commonly found on the walls of UK public toilets...

> Here I sit broken hearted,
>   Paid a penny and only farted

In practice, I think the most common phrasing is just [a lot of effort for little reward](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20lot%20of%20effort%20for%20little%20reward%22&oq=%22a%20lot%20of%20effort%20for%20little%20reward%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.45859902&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but in my particular neck of the woods I often hear [life's too short to stuff a mushroom](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22life%27s%20too%20short%20to%20stuff%20a%20mushroom%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

*As I've just discovered, the American version of this is very definitely [tempest in a teapot](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tempest%20in%20a%20teapot,storm%20in%20a%20teacup&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: "Tried to shit but only farted" is how I've heard it on this side of the pond.

Comment: @Robusto: I've seen "paid a dime" in my earlier days, but, once paid toilets went out of vogue, the version you quote gained more traction. Wish I could run an Ngram on this.

Comment: FumbleFingers. I can really, really sympathize with the feeling, ‘Paid a penny and only farted’ in recollection of the days I studied in China long time ago, and used to use paid toilets in downtown and the provinces there. I think I paid 3角 (0.3 yuan) at a time.

Comment: ^ I can confirm 3-jiao toilets from back when I visited Beijing when I was 8. More recently I believe they were 0.5 to 1 yuan.

Comment: There's also [rush around like] a [fart in a colander](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fart+in+a+colander%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I usually hear that in reference to energetic activity with *no real purpose*, but I suppose sometimes it could suit @Yoichi's context.

Comment: Interesting. I've always heard this (in the USA) as "tempest in a teapot".

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's [really](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tempest+in+a+teapot%2Cstorm+in+a+teacup&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) interesting! I have sometimes come across your version, but I'd no idea how sharply UK/US usage splits over this one. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_in_a_teapot) seems to be saying *both* versions originally came from Brits - *tempest/teapot* came first, but for some reason we switched to *storm/teapot* quite early, and stuck to that thereafter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's always baffled me why the British didn't stick with the "tempest" version. The alliteration is so much more satisfying, and an excellent counterbalance to its mountain/molehill cousin.

Comment: @nohat: It's never baffled me before because I'd never really registered the US prevalence of the other version until now. And it *still* doesn't really baffle me, because of course I've always known the UK version, so it seems perfectly natural to me (perhaps I'm just a little surprised that Americans can't see how natural *our* version is, and thus fail to adopt it themselves! :)

Comment: I'm kinda with you Brits on this one, simply because the word "tempest" is otherwise so rare over here that most folks don't even know what it means. Its far more practical to use the modern word. Still, its a shame to lose such a neat word, so I guess I'm glad we kept it. :-)

Comment: T.E.D.: After the ambivalent reaction I got over [ripe/rife with opportunity](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33721/2637), I've learnt it doesn't usually pay to defend UK over US usage on ELU! But I wouldn't worry about losing [The Tempest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tempest) so long as Anglophones continue to revere the Bard.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps Shakespeare's oft quoted line from Macbeth

> . . .it is a tale told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, signifying nothing.

The full quote is an even more dramatic commentary on an entire life being lived to little outcome

> Out, out, brief candle! Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player that struts and frets his hour upon the stage and then is heard no more: it is a tale told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, signifying nothing."

Comment: Hey, look, one I've heard before!  +1 for the part of the Macbeth quote in the first quote block.  It's close, at least.

Answer (score 10):

I think "all heat, no light" carries a similar meaning, and is usually used specifically in connection with debates and discussions, as in a "heated discussion" that does not result in any insights (i.e., "no light").

Answer (score 8):

Using a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Comment: Similar: Using an elephant gun to kill a gnat.

Comment: This seems amongst the most appropriate and idiomatic answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in that case the question as a whole is a duplicate. A vote for this answer is a vote to close. Meanwhile the OP expressly states that he is *not* looking for people to repeat answers from that older question.

Comment: Note that it is not easy to find the older question to which the OP refers simply by reading the question.

Comment: I was unaware of an older question or the OP stating that we shouldn't repeat answers from it.

Comment: @RegDwight: You're quite right. It's among the most appropriate and idiomatic answers to the question Mikhail put. I'll try and get my brain in gear.

Answer (score 6):

*[Wild-goose chase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wild-goose_chase#English)* is close — although it would be usually be interpreted as "big fuss, **no** results", it is sometime used when there is a successful conclusion in spite of the twisted turns of the process.

For a less poetic, but common phrase, *more effort than it’s worth* and *more trouble than it’s worth* spring to mind.

Answer (score 6):

Virtually the same thought was, as Konrad Rudolph points out, expressed in Latin by Horace, *Parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus*, and through frequent quotation the idea has become proverbial in English. Here's a collection of usages:

> When I such guests did see come out of such a house,
> The mountaines great with childe I thought brought foorth a mouse. - Sidney, *Arcadia* ca 1580
>
> *But I doubt* (ſays G.R.) *it will prove but a Mouſe brought forth by the long labour and hard throes of Mountain.  —Sage, *Fundamental Charter* 1695
>
> All parties united in patching up a reconciliation, to avoid the laugh that muſt ever follow, when “A mountain in labour has brought forth a mouſe.”  —*Sporting Magazine* 1793
>
> Like the mountain in the fable, it seems to me, the Ways and Means Committee has labored and brought forth a mouse in the shape of the Payne bill—a miserable makeshift and the merest aplogy for real tariff reform. —Speech in US Congress 1909
>
> Common Cause, the self-appointed, so-called “citizens lobby”, which is a mountain among the other self-appointed, so-called “citizens lobbies” in this city, has labored mightily and brought forth a mouse. —Newspaper column 1977
>
> The Debt Mountain Labored and Brought Forth a Mouse —headline in *National Review Online* 2011

Comment: This was [one of Aesop's fables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mountain_in_Labour) as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could call this

> A tempest in a teapot

That is [a very common expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_in_a_teapot).

There is a similar expression in Japanese: コップの中の嵐. Does that have the same feeling to you?

Comment: Rubusto-san. The literal translation ofコップの中の嵐is “Tempest in a glass.” To me 'コップの中の嵐' seems to be a bit different from '大山鳴動鼠一匹.' The former means ‘to make a fruitless quarrel by making a great fuss in the same group or organization,’ like chronic internal conflict in Japan’s Democratic Party who lost to LDP in the latest Lower House election, because people were fed up with their internal skirmish, while the latter means ‘Big fuss, tiny result – Much ado about nothing’

Comment: I've heard this more commonly as "storm in a teacup", but yes.

Comment: "Een storm in een glas water" (Storm in a glass of water) in Dutch.

Comment: Just to say I didn't crib this one off you - I added it a couple of hours ago after T.E.D. had commented on my answer that he was more familiar with (what I now know to be) the US version of UK *storm in a teacup*. But I've just scrolled down to see if anyone's already mentioned *don't sweat the small stuff*, to discover there are a lot more answers now than there were before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, you could have given attribution in your answer instead of burying it in a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

"All hat and no cattle."  --- From Texas! :-)

The direct interpretation is that the person dresses like a rancher or cowboy (i.e. [has a ten gallon hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_hat#.22Ten_gallon.22_hat)), but does not own any cattle.

The implied meaning is that the person is [all talk and no substance](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all%20hat,%20no%20cattle).

Comment: Beautiful! I love it. But I'm a little suspicious of its meaning being "showing off but having no substance," as of someone who makes an ostentatious display of talent or wealth but has it not. Could you please elaborate on the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: @Sathyaish: Done!

Comment: I love this one too (as an Okie who has actually worked cattle), and went into this Q specifically looking for it. However, I can't bring myself to upvote it here because its more about being a complete loudmouth poseur than about something turning out to not be quite as big a deal as made out.

Comment: the British version is [all mouth, but no trousers](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/511.html)

Comment: @downvoter: Any comment as to why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

It's more of a [meme](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=all%20got%20lousy%20shirt&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=xQsAUaTTCenx0wH3p4G4BA&biw=1268&bih=656&sei=xwsAUfWFI8aH0QG_-YDYDw) or [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AndAllIGotWasThisLousyTShirt) than a common idiom, but the first thing that came to my mind was the Lousy Shirt.

If you were to generalize it and say something like this, I think most english speakers would understand the reference.

> **I [made a big fuss] and all I got was this lousy [result]!**

Answer (score 4):

There is also the "[*without much to show for it*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22much%20to%20show%20for%20it%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#hl=en&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&tok=Z9sJrkGAdAlf2XoBLt8F5w&ds=bo&pq=%22much%20to%20show%20for%20it%22&cp=21&gs_id=9oo&xhr=t&q=%22not+much+to+show+for%22&es_nrs=true&pf=p&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbo=d&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1992%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22not+much+to+show+for%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.b2I&fp=b8b50995caebdbe7&biw=1435&bih=682&bs=1)" expression.

This can be combined with many different verb phrases:

> For example:
>   We put forth a huge effort *without much to show for it.*
>   We've spent millions and *don't have much to show for it*.
>   He stayed up all night studying *but doesn't have much to show for it*.

Comment: I never thought of this one, but you're quite right - it's a fairly common expression that invariably nets down to exactly OP's *Big effort **:** Small result* juxtaposition.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, you could describe a "big fuss with tiny result" simply as *overkill*.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not much heard, but *All gong and no dinner* might be close to the spirit of the Japanese, although it presages not so much a little result as no result at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's always the quote from Haggai 1:

*You have sown much, and harvested little.*

It readily lends itself to metaphorical usage and change of person, and would usually be recognised as being wry rather than pretentious.

Answer (score 2):

There's also "all sizzle and no steak".

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the phrase "Using a siege gun to kill a gnat" (actually I think it was in a novel).

Comment: Authors seem to compete to create their own versions of this simile.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there similar English sayings to express “大山鳴動鼠一匹 - Big fuss, tiny
>   result”?

**Dud**: a person or thing that proves ineffectual or a failure, ***or does not meet expectations***.

**Fizzle**: To fail or end weakly, ***especially after a hopeful beginning***. A failure. a fiasco.

You might hear someone say "That turned out to be a dud." Or "That fizzled."

This is a metaphoric reference to the expectation of an explosion where one did not, in fact, occur.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one from *A Complete Collection of Scottish Proverbs, Collected, Explain'd, and Made Intelligible to the English* (1721), by James Kelly:

"A great Cry and little Wool quoth the Deel when he clip'd the swine."

The author comments: "Spoken of great Pretences and small Performances." "Deel," I believe, is an old Scottish pronunciation of "Devil."

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related is a reply I offered on a similar thread. The link to the thread is 
[A situation when you do too many thing but achieve nothing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101191/a-situation-when-you-do-too-many-thing-but-achieve-nothing/101208#101208)

I am going to repeat my reply here:

You're looking for the expression *spinning your wheels*.

```
Example: They're on the grind spinning their wheels.
```

You can also invent your own expressions such as:

```
Circling around in circles (suggesting no movement or direction inspite of activity)

They're pushing too hard, a door that needs pulling.

Or they're pulling what needs pushing.

They're pushing a brick wall.

They're busy chewing the stones.

They're busy chewing the rocks.

They're taking one step forward and two steps back.

They're trying to fleece leather out of a sheep.

They're working hard counting the hairs on their own heads.

They're making about turns to get there.
```