# What is the word to describe a situation where one makes a big deal out of things that can be done with little effort?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What would be the word(s) or an idiom to describe a situation where a person is portraying the situation as if it is a lot of effort to do something when in fact it can be accomplished with just a little effort?

Comment: [Marshmallow-rice puffery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZXoGZijH4)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there popular English sayings to express “Big fuss, tiny result”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101152/are-there-popular-english-sayings-to-express-big-fuss-tiny-result)

Comment: "Drama-queening" seems to be a word. I'm not sure how I feel about that, but it is what came to mind. [The Cat Who Wasn't a Dog
By Marian Babson](https://books.google.com/books?id=06fPJvFtj8IC&lpg=PA204&ots=hWEso_awVd&dq=%22drama-queening%22&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q=%22drama-queening%22&f=false)

Comment: for 'word-choice' I would go with; exaggerate

Answer (score 36):

> "**Making a mountain out of a molehill**"
>
> An idiom referring to over-reactive, histrionic behaviour where a person makes too much of a minor issue.
>
> [Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)

Answer (score 5):

> **"to over-egg"**
>
> in phrase *over-egg the pudding*: Go too far in embellishing,
>   exaggerating, or doing something. ‘if you're telling fibs, keep them
>   simple—never over-egg the pudding’
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/over-egg

example: "I think he's over-egging it!"

Answer (score 2):

***A hoo-ha***, from the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88279?redirectedFrom=hoo-hah#eid)

> A commotion, a rumpus, a row.

The OED gives several examples; the one most pertinent to the OP's question is:

> 1971   Country Life 27 May 1328/2   Some of these lovely irises
>   may..be grown..successfully without much hoo-ha.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoo-ha) says:

> great excitement or concern about something.

An example, which I made up, of the usage the OP is looking for:

> Sandy made a big hoo-ha about preparing dinner, but all she did was
>   microwave a frozen pizza and open a bottle of wine.

Answer (score 1):

in a word, hyperbole - hy·per·bo·le.
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyperbole

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

ado
noun
1.
fuss, especially about something that is unimportant.
"on the face of it, this is much ado about almost nothing"
2.
trouble or difficulty.
"she had much ado to keep up with him"

Comment: Quotes need to be properly attributed in order to avoid possible breach-of-copyright legislation.

Comment: "Ado" itself doesn't mean making a situation seem more complicated than it is. "Much ado about nothing", is a phrase that works, however some may find its usage archaic.

Answer (score 0):

Or an idiom from the German language

> make an elephant out of a mosquito

Comment: The dutch language has the same saying, but I wouldn't us this in English

Comment: We have a camel.